# WinRT App Viewbox control flickers when first loaded

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, viewbox

I am working on a Windows Store App that has a WebView control wrapped by a ViewBox to provide proper scaling. This is working great except for the fact that the screen loads great but then flickers about 500ms afterwards.

During the flicker I can see the screen resize briefly. I am not sure why it would go from properly sized to some mystery size back to properly sized.

This is a horrible user experience and I need to find a resolution. Anyone experienced this and found a fix?

The code is basic, but here it is.

```
<Viewbox Stretch="UniformToFill" x:Name="PresentationViewBox">
   <WebView x:Name="WebPresentation">
   </WebView>
</Viewbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being some hidden code I inherited that was resizing the control twice.